# pixel value change after image rotate

Tags: python, opencv, rotation

Is it possible the value pixel of image is change after image rotate? I rotate an image, ex, I rotate image 13 degree, so I pick a random pixel before the image rotate and say it X, then I brute force in image has been rotate, and I not found pixel value as same as X. so is it possible the value pixel can change after image rotate? I rotate with opencv library in python.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what function do you use to rotate? typically image transformations include interpolation so the pixel values can/will differ slightly

Comment: I am using opencv function to rotate image.

Comment: which function? warpAffine?

Comment: yes, it is. img2 = cv2.warpAffine(img, rotation_mat, (bound_w, bound_h))

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you just rotate the same image plane the image pixels will remain same. Simple maths

Comment: do you have an idea to rotate image using matrix rotation?

Comment: Here opencv eg http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/warp_affine/warp_affine.html

Comment: they will not remain the same, you need to apply some interpolation to will gaps in result image

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible for the initial pixel value not to be found in the transformed image.

To understand why this would happen, remember that pixels are not infinitely small dots, but they are rectangles with *horizontal* and *vertical* sides, with small but non-zero width and height.

After a 13 degrees rotation, these rectangles (which have constant color inside) will not have their sides horizontal and vertical anymore.

Therefore an approximation needs to be made in order to represent the rotated image using pixels of constant color, with sides horizontal and vertical.

Comment: so pixel after rotate not represent pixel before rotate? I understand now

Comment: indeed, there is not a perfect match between pixels before the rotation and pixels after the rotation.