# After rotating a matrix, some points disappear, and some points are duplicated

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, rotation

I have a matrix containing positions of some items (x1, x2, x3, x4, x5):

[Matrix before rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2q5Yb.png)

And I want to apply a 55° rotation using scipy.ndimage.rotate method:
np_after = ndimage.rotate(df, angle, reshape = False, order = 0)

After rotation, I obtain the following matrix:

[Matrix after rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXc88.png)

My points "x1", "x3", "x4" have disappeared, and my point "x5" has been duplicated.

Do you have an idea how to be sure we have each point translated in the rotated matrix, and only one time?

Thanks !!

Comment: The answer is in `scipy.ndimage.rotate` documentation: "The array is rotated in the plane defined by the two axes given by the axes parameter using spline interpolation of the requested order". There is no guarantee that any particular pixel value will be in the result.

Comment: Thanks @nonDucor, is there any rotate algorithm that would suits requester needs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pixel value change after image rotate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36532089/pixel-value-change-after-image-rotate)

Comment: I'm not aware of any and, in fact, the two requirements seem conflicting: if you rotate by an arbitrary angle, your original pixels will not always fall on top of the rotated image pixels (that is still a rectangular grid). So in general you'll have interpolation.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. It seems there is no rotate algorithm that could solve this issue and I understand why.

To solve this, we have decided to approximate the position of disappearing points by adding an empy column to the matrix and proceed to the same rotation (this changes the points that duplicate or disappear). 

And we have dropped the duplicates randomly keeping only the first occurrence.